# Mean App, adding object to db then outputting under new div

Tags: angular

Hi I was just curious when using angular and setting up a factory to save and get objects from db if I save it how do I then move itemA from listA to listB? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of items bound to listA and another array of items bound to listB, then simply remove the item from the first array and add it to the second array.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
numbers.push(4);

console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Oh really so simple is that because of two way data binding?

Comment: You'd only really need 1-way binding in this case.